# Problem during preprocessing of data in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, mnist

I'm getting some errors while trying to follow tensorflow's own Quickstart. My problem is: I'm trying to implement it using a custom dataset, and I'm having some trouble figuring out how the MNIST dataset is preprocessed.

Here is a code from the documentation that loads the data:

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

Keras' documentation reads that load_data() returns a tuple of Numpy arrays, however I can't for the life of me figure out how to prepare datasets from `tensorflow_datasets` in the same way you can prepare Keras datasets. Is it even possible?

I've already tried using

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
builder = tfds.builder("mnist")
assert builder.info.splits['train'].num_examples == 60000
builder.download_and_prepare()
datasets = builder.as_dataset()
(x_train, y_train), (_, _) = tfds.as_numpy(datasets)
```

but as anticipated this doesn't work.

Any ideas, or am I going to have to learn to use tensorflow_datasets using a different resource?

Comment: Hello there, Saeur. Welcome to SO! 
Let me understand what you're trying to do: you're trying to run the MNIST example using different datasets? Or you're trying to figure out how to preprocess your data?

Comment: @CelsoWellington Thank you! I suppose here I'm trying to modify the Beginner code so that I can use a different dataset instead of the ones provided with Keras - all the examples I've found on Tensorflow's website only use Keras' datasets so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: You need to study about data pre-processing. The MNIST dataset / model treat low-resolution images with monochanel (one color only). You need to analyze your train data to adapt it (and, of course, normalize it by dividing by 255).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to load the dataset using tfds

```
(train_image, train_label),(test_image,test_label) = tfds.as_numpy(tfds.load(
      'mnist',
      split='train',
      batch_size=-1,
      as_supervised=True,
  )), tfds.as_numpy(tfds.load(
      'mnist',
      split='test',
      batch_size=-1,
      as_supervised=True,
  ))
```